# AngularJS: Change input value with server data when page loads

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

Sorry if this was already asked, but I really didn't find anything that applies exactly to my problem.

Well, although I know that an AngularJS form value must be loaded from controllers and that I can create routes and RESTful resources with AngularJS, I am using Python and Flask to get the page and data but AngularJS to post data to the server. The problem is, when I put "ng-model" within a text input, the value from server is ignored, like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="first_name" value={{user.first_name}}>
```

is interpreted as:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="first_name" value="John" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

but the value cannot be seen, as if there is no "value" attribute.

Given that situation, I tried to use directives, but I didn't realise how to get this server data and share it with another scope.

What I want is to simply load a page with server data inside a ng-model input and access it through controller methods later ("placeholder" is useless here).

I am sending the page like this:

```
class ShowUser(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        s = Session(request)
        if s.is_logged():
            user = dict({'username': s.user.username, 'first_name': s.user.first_name, 'last_name': s.user.last_name,
                         'email': s.user.email, 'logged': True})
            return render_template('users/show-user.html', user=user)
        else:
            user = dict({'username': 'null', 'logged': False})
            return render_template('index.html', user=user)
```

It's that "user" variable in "render_template" that I am trying to access.

Comment: You shouldn't use `value` and `ng-model` together. `ng-model` takes the place of `value`. If `$scope.first_name` isn't being set in your controller than the input value will not change. Can you verify `first_name` is being set by whatever web service you are using? Also, if `first_name` is being set, but it's outside the scope of angular, you'll want to wrap it in an `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: The server part is all ok. The problem is, It's impossible to do: `$scope.$apply('foo = {{user.first_name}}');`. I just don't know how to put a server-processed string inside a Angular controller scope.

Comment: How are you loading the data from the server? It must be getting loaded in the controller. Whatever request you make, you can set `first_name` in the response handler. And that will just do what you want. It'd be better if you can share how you are loading data from the server.

Comment: I don't know python and at this point it is irrelvant(granted your python is working), but how are you making the `$http` call in your controller? That is what @vaidik was asking

Comment: Thank you for your replies @vaidik and @Ronnie. I figured out a crazy way of doing it, now I can explain myself better. Doing `<span ng-bind="loadData({{user}})"></span>`, where "loadData" is a controller method, I can actually access the data. I am not doing $http.get to get this page, that is the problem.

Comment: And the problem with `<span ng-bind="loadData({{user}})"></span>` is that it makes the input impossible do edit, because it calls "loadData" every change I make within the form.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you are eventually making an HTTP request whose response in Angular must be handled asynchronously. And when you handle the response, you can do what you want. What you need to show is the controller code and the template.

Comment: I am not getting the page through Angular controller, there is nothing related to show. That is exactly my problem, I don't know how to do this, the routing is already made with python and it loads the data ok, but I don't know how to deal with this using Angular. I can follow a tutorial of "routing in Angular" but this is not my problem. I don't even know the terms to look for an answer. And sorry to bother you, @vaidik

Comment: Oh oh. So you are trying to access `user` variable passed from your flask controller to your flask template (i.e. `index.html`) and use it inside angular?

Comment: Yes, and I don't know how to "do the talking" using Angular. What should I use? Nothing seems to answer my question. The html is loaded with a string and I just can't access through Angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to the server, you can write an angular `.value()` in the page (I assume {{ }} is from your SERVER-side templating here, NOT Angular's):

```
<script>
angular.module('app').value('User', {{user}});
</script>
```

better example, in EJS, you could have:

```
<script>
angular.module('app').value('User', <%= JSON.stringify(user) %>);
</script>
```

This must be placed anywhere AFTER the `.js` that contains your initial `angular.module('app', [...])`

Then inject `User` in your controller and scope;

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'User',
    function($scope, User) {
      $scope.user = User;
    }
    ]);
```

Finally, in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.first_name" />
```